# LWC - When to use FlowAttributeChangeEvent?

Tags: lightning-web-components, visual-workflow

I'm confused around the use case for throwing particular event.

I have an LWC with an @api getter and a private setter. This ioSelections is marked in my targetConfig as a flow attribute in order for this collection to be communicated out to the flow.

Can please someone explain why this is working without throwing the FlowAttributeChangeEvent every time an entry is inserted into the selections collection? I was under the impression that I needed to throw this event, but it looks like that isn't the case. I'm confused because the official documentation mentions to throw this event *"when mapping the value of output attributes to flow variables"* but it is working correctly with the setup below and no throwing of the event.

Do you only throw this event when you have some other component element on the screen that needs to dynamically change based on the output value from the lwc?

Example:

```
    @track selections = [];
    @track errors = [];

    @api
    get ioSelections(){
        console.log('get ioSelections called');
        return this.selections;
    }

    set ioSelections(value){
        console.log('set ioSelections called');
        this.selections = value;
    }
```

[image]

Thank you